# What are the steps to run ES6 syntax in node.js?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

What are the required steps to start writing ES6 syntax in node.js? Currently I'm planning to write the below codes, but it gives me error

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.json("Does't work es6");
});
```

I did `nodemon server --harmony`

Anyone who could provide the steps would be appreciated.

Comment: Update to the latest Node version and your code should work.

Comment: Depends on the version you use. For v4.x using strict mode in the file will do the job (harmony flag is not required)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this table](http://node.green/) to see what ES6 support your version of Node has and polyfill anything unsupported using [Babel register](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/).

Or update to the latest version of Node and your example will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

please update your node to 4.x or later

you can check node version by running

```
node -v
```

then start your app by just running

```
node server.js
```

that's it